# Unable to locate symbol inside shared library (.so)

Tags: c, linux, debugging, shared-libraries

I am trying to map the address of a function that is supposed to exist inside a shared library (.so). I am sucessfully able to open the library and am trying to get the address of the function inside it as such:

```
fn_read = dlsym (handle, "functionName");
```

However I am getting an error, and upon inspection the error is that the symbol could not be found. I am pretty sure that I am making this call correctly. I am also 100% sure that the function that I am trying to map is included in the shared library itself. I'm not sure what to do here...could someone please point out some possible mistakes/points that I may be overlooking?

Thanks, 
Fal

Comment: if you do `nm -D /path/to/your/lib.so` do you see the function name listed?

Comment: are you sure "functionName" is not a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the unix/linux command `nm -g <library>.so`.  It will list all of your `C` style symbols.

Note that C++ participates in "name mangling", so if you don't have a "C style" symbol exported, odds are the name was mangled and isn't directly reachable.  `nm -gC <library>.so` will also show the mangled C++ names.

If you are attempting to access a C++ symbol, and name mangling is causing the problem, following the guidelines in the [C++ FAQ light on mixing C and C++](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html) can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If the symbol is truly there, the only reasonable cause is that `functionName` is a C++ function which has not been declared `extern "C"`. You can either add the `extern "C"` component, or determine the mangled name and locate that instead.

Comment: I am looking at the source code for the shared library. The function is a c function.

Comment: If the function is c, then the likelyhood is that the symbol is just not there. Use the `nm` command @Edwin_Buck suggests to determine if it's there. If it's not there, the symbol may have been built with attributes to not allow its export. Compiling under gcc with `-fvisibility=hidden` sets symbols to be hidden by default, and `__attribute__ ((visibility("default")))` on a symbol definition makes it exported.